# configService.get() cannot read env variable from .env file in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-config

I am trying to set TypeOrm configuration object using env variables in NestJS. The configuration object should read `'DB_NAME'` env variable(set to `db.sqlite`) set in a `.development.env` file. The env variable is provided via `configService.get('DB_NAME)` api of `@nestjs/config` library. My code in `app.module.ts` files is as follows:

```
   import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
    import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';


    @Module({
      imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({
        isGlobal: true,
        envFilePath: `.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`
      }), TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
        imports: [ConfigModule],
        inject: [ConfigService],
        useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => {
console.log(config.get('DB_NAME'))  //for testing purpose only; returns undefined 
          return {
            type: 'sqlite',
            database: config.get('DB_NAME'),
            entities: [User, Report],
            synchronize: true
          }
        }
      }), UsersModule, ReportsModule],
      controllers: [AppController],
      providers: [AppService, {
        provide: APP_PIPE,
        useValue: new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true })
      }],
    })
```

since config.get('DB_NAME') is undefined, database connection fails and in the console following error is thrown:

```
DriverOptionNotSetError: Driver option (database) is not set. Please set it to perform connection to the database.
```

Also receiving undefined while trying to read `COOKIE_SESSION` env variable inside appModule  class using same `this.configService.get('COOKIE_SESSION')`. The configService in injected using a constructor inside appModule.

Answer (score 1):

try to change your .env file to

> .env.development

And rewrite code as

```
envFilePath: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`
```

Answer (score -1):

try adding ConfigService in providers

```
providers: [AppService, {
  provide: APP_PIPE,
  useValue: new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true })
}, ConfigService]
```

Comment: it did not work.